# Find users who have a specific role

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, user-roles

My code is:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var teaching = db.Teachings.Include(d =>d.Course).Include(d=>d.Group).Include(d => d.User);

    return View(await teaching.ToListAsync());
}
```

And I want to know how can I filter some roles, I mean, how can I filter only the users who has an specific role, if I can.

I think a possible solution could be `....Include(d => d.Users).Where(...)`, but I don't know how to compare the role of the user that I am taking, with a specific role.

My roles are teacher, admin or student.

In conclusion, filter only the users whose role is "teacher" .

Comment: You'll need to include the table definitions in your question, including how they relate, for anything other than a wild guess.

Comment: I think you should review your model. There are logical differences between teachers, students and admin. I think you should create a student table and a teacher table. Admin is actually a role which means nothing to your model. Then you can keep authorization where it is, in the IdentityContext, while you can query 'Teachings' by just joining the student table (or teachers table).

Comment: It´s a university proyect and i can´t modify my database tables. My teacher added us teachers, students and admin as a role and i can´t change that, and i have to manage myself with that. @RuardvanElburg

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using Identity Framework provided by ASP.net, you can just use the UserManager to achieve that.

In UserManager, it has a function for you, which is GetUsersInRoleAsync(string roleName). This will return you with a list of users in the role.

You could just do

```
var userThatYouWant = await _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("RoleName");
```

And voila, the list will contain all the users with the role that you have specified.

This is assuming if you have initialised _userManager properly.

Comment: Question is not tagged asp.net-core

Answer (score 1):

You can write one linq to do this for you, select all teachers that associated with users that **any** of their roles is equal to teacher,  which is written like this, for your reference

```
var teaching = db.Teachings
                    .Include(d =>d.Course)
                    .Include(d=>d.Group)
                    .Include(d => d.User)
                    .Include(d => d.User.Roles)
                    .Where(d => d.User.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == "teacher")));
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to use Identity's UserManager class. It has a **UserInRole** function which returns a bool. What you can do is iterate through the users and check against this function.

Sample:

```
foreach(var user in Users)
{
    var isInRole = UserManager.UserInRole(user, "RoleName");
}
```

Comment: Though I agree you should use the Usermanager, iterating through the users is not the solution since this would mean you would have to fetch the users first and then call the database for eacht user to get the role. It would be better to extend the UserManager with a function that does something like the name suggests: GetUsersInRoleAsync

Answer (score -1):

maybe you can try:
db.Teachings.Include(d =>d.Course).Include(d=>d.Group).Include(d => d.User.Where(us=> ur.Role =="teacher"));

I hope this helps!